# Why is my windows 10 machine's internet getting 30mb via wifi on a 650 mb connection?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, internet-speed

I have a 650mb/s connection from virgin media, which is mostly working fine, I get anywhere up to 600-650mb/s on every device I I own (samsing s20, iphone 11, 2 macbook pros) except for my Windows 10 PC.

Now I will say, I only have a 300mb/s capable card, so i know i won't get the full speed, but i'm consistently getting 30-50 mb/s down on this device.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Switching to Ethernet (this works, speed jumps to 600-650mbs, but is not a viable long term solution given the path from router to PC)
2. moving the PC closer to the router (moved it to within 5 feet, unobstructed, no change in speed)
3. I set the autotuning level to normal via cmd
4. I tried flushing the DNS via cmd, this threw no errors, but changed nothing speed wise
5. Checked my programs list for any bloatware of application that would possibly limit my speed, anything I was unsure of, I removed, including the nvidea suite that did nothing to help the speed and was a pain to reinstall
6. Spoke to Virgin Media who told me the problem was definitely on my end and there was nothing they could do

I'm at my wits end. If I don't find a solution to this, I'm going to have my house totally wired with cat6 so wifi is no longer an issue for any reason.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have attached a screengrab from SamKnows to show the inconsistency between connection to router and connection to machine.

Thanks!

[samknows speed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/548g9.jpg)

Comment: Make sure your wireless card is a high quality AC card. Your speeds look like N speeds

Comment: Try another wireless adapter of good quality, even a USB one.

Comment: According to the supplier, I have a "WIRELESS 802.11N 300Mbps/2.4GHz PCI-E CARD", according to device manager, I have a "Realtek RTL8192EE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC", I'll buy a T3U AC 1300 on amazon and see if that does the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The word Realtec says all you need to know. They make the cralpuest xards  You should replace the card with anything else.  (you might also be suffering from their crappy drivers as well  Sometimes changing the driver can help - but really, just ditch the card)

Comment: @Harvey - You should go for a higher quality WiFi 6 adapter.  `802.11ac AC1200` is near the bottom of the barrel, a device like that, won't bring you that much of a speed increase.

Comment: The reason I bought the T3U is because it's a cheap and effective way to see if the speed increased at all, and would allow me to determine if the card was the issue.
Turns out, it was the issue, now I'm in the market for a new card, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies in the data that point to the culprit.

- The numbers for upload speed are about the same. All the other data for jitter and latency match up. The only disparity is download speed.
- Another red flag is your statement.
  "moving the PC closer to the router (moved it to within 5 feet, unobstructed, no change in speed)" -
  a wireless device should show an improvement in speed closer to the router.
- Your statement about the 2.4GHz 802.11N is another red flag. Read about channel bonding - https://www.lifewire.com/get-300-mbps-speed-on-802-11n-network-818267

Basically your card has a max theoretical speed of 150mbps. The actual max speed is even lower - https://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-the-actual-real-life-speed-of-wireless-374

So, the actual max speed of 40mbps for a single channel 802.11N is about right.